# Get all classes that extends a class in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, oop, reflection

so basically I have a this code where classes extends over a base class

```
class CommandBase {
    doCommand(){
        // Do command thing.
    }
}

class Help extends CommandBase{

}

class Kick extends CommandBase{
    
}

class Ban extends CommandBase{
    
}

class Chat extends CommandBase{
    
}
```

now throughout the production of the program more and more commands will be added that extends the CommandBase class, is there any way via reflection I can just get all classes the extends the CommandBase classes without to explicitly write them in an array or keeping track of them by writing manually on code? I want to have something like this in C#:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p))
```

Can nodeJS do this? is there any specific reflection library for it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to do this with reflections or similar techniques.

You could write a little pre-processor that iterates over your files, looks for `/class\s+([\S]+)\s+extends\s+CommandBase/g` and stores the results in a form  that can be used for the actual code execution.

Comment: so basically we're going to read the .js files and gets the names of the class? alright this looks good, but is there also a way I can create an instance of the class just via having the names? for example I have the string "Ban", I want to create an instance of this class just having its name

Comment: I was able to create something similar by putting all commands (which all exports the function "doCommand()") in a folder and whenever the user does a command let's say "/ping", I just make the bot program find a file named "ping.js" inside the command folder, require it, and invoke the "doCommand()" function.